# Do I need to sign apps for Windows Store?

Tags: windows, certificate, signing

I have developed a hybrid application for Windows 8.1 that I want to submit to the app store. As the app package requirements, it does not look at like I need to sign my package using any a trusted certificate. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694075.aspx

I am using VS 2013 to create my project and my app package. Is the default certificate enough ?

Can some one who has submitted apps for approval, please speak about their experience regarding the app signing and if/how one can get this certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I was able to submit the app. I was able to sign the app once I linked my store account.